# Custom header in angular material accordion

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I customize `<mat-panel-title>` to support a subtitle under a header? I try to add some HTML tags but not work.
For now i have this:

[image]

[my stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-materialaccordion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flex-box display:

```html
<mat-panel-title style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
  <span>HEADER</span>
  <span>subtitle</span>
</mat-panel-title>
```

But do it using a css class selector.

#### In css file:

```css
.column-layout {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

#### In your template:

```html
<mat-panel-title class="column-layout">
  <span>HEADER</span>
  <span>subtitle</span>
</mat-panel-title>
```